# Does anyone know the style of what beast boy is playing in the link?

Tags: guitar

Hi guys have any one noticed this clip from S01E14 : 4:45.
He plays a sad tone with guitar, i guess its Spanish style, the wonderful thing i realized being a guitarist myself is that the detailing the director and the animators have taken...Coz the fingering and the strumming are so perfect that we can actually see the correct strings vibrating and can identify the chord progression : D, A, Bm
The style and rhyme got into my heart that i felt this is a worth share, hope all the guitarists and teen titan fans would enjoy this clip for its worth. Great work and effort to the teen titans team ;)
And yes it does look like the pattern from "Fleetwood Mac - Landslide" ;).

Comment: I have popped up an answer, but I'm not at all sure this question belongs here. It feels a lot like asking what genre a track is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not class this as Spanish style. It doesn't follow any picking rhythms that are really indicative of Spanish or Flamenco.

I wouldn't really class it under classical style either.

It is a fairly basic fingerpicking style - used in a lot of popular ballads.